# Show that if $A,B$ are measurable, $A\subset E\subset B$, and $m(A)=m(B)$, then $E$ is measurable.

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-measure

Here's the full problem:

> Suppose $A\subset E\subset B$, where $A,B$ are measurable with finite measure. Show that if $m(A)=m(B)$, then $E$ is measurable.

Here, we are dealing with measure space $(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{M},m)$. I come here just to see if this is a valid proof. Here we go:

> **Proof**
>
> We have that $m(A),m(B)<\infty$. Supposing $m(A)=m(B)$, we have
>
> $$m(A)\leq m(E) \leq m(B)=m(A)$$
>   $$\implies m(A)=m(E)$$
>
> Since $A$ is measurable, it follows that $E$ must then be measruable.

I know of another way to prove this, I was just wondering if this was a valid argument as well.

Comment: It is false without completeness of measure.

Comment: If $m$ Lebesgue measure?

Comment: Yes $m$ is Lebesgue measure. Thank you the responses guys. I figured the argument was hollow, I just wanted clarification :)

Answer (score 5):

You have got to be careful! you cannot write $m(E)$ before knowing that it is measurable! :)

This is how I would prove the result:

By assumption $m(B) - m(A) = 0$, hence $m(B \setminus A) = 0$. To make this precise I need to use that $A \subset B$: $$ 0 = m(B) - m(A) = m(A) + m(B \setminus A) - m(A) = m(B\setminus A).$$

Now that we have this, denote by $m^*$ the outer measure (which is defined on every set, hence we can make sense of $m^*(E)$!). Recall also that for measurable sets $m^* = m$.

To prove that $E$ is measurable I am going to write it as the union of two measurable sets: $A$ and $E\setminus A$. Of course we don't know yet that the latter is measurable, but follows from the previous computation and the **completeness** of the measure (which I guess I can assume): $$m^*(E \setminus A) \le m^*(B \setminus A) = m(B \setminus A) = 0.$$

Hopefully I got it right :D

Comment: More rigorous then the proof I was thinking! Well done. This is my alternate:

$m(B\setminus A)=0$ since $m(A),m(B)<\infty$ and $m(A)=m(B)$. So $B\setminus A$ is a null set, hence measurable. Since $(B\setminus A) \supseteq (E\setminus A)$ and we know subsets of nulls sets are also null sets, it follows that $E\setminus A$ is a null set. Hence, $E\setminus A$ is measurable and since $E=A\cup (E\setminus A)$, $E$ must be measurable (since the union of measurable sets is measurable).

Comment: lol, this is exactly my proof ahahah :) Also, you need to use that $A \subset B$ since otherwise it does not work (A = [0,1], B = [2,3]. m(A) = m(B) = 1 but m(B \ A) = 1)

Answer (score 2):

You assumed that $E$ is measurable when you wrote
$$ m(A) \le m(E) \le m(B) $$
It's clear that *if* $m(E)$ is defined, then it must be equal to the common value of $m(A)$ and $m(B)$.  The issue is how we know it's defined at all.

Answer (score 1):

This is true if the measure involved is complete.